# Swipe View with buttons in a relativeLayout, out of the fragment

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, fragment, swipe

I am new to Android programming.
I have the following layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fundo"
        android:background="@color/roxo"
        tools:context="com.fnsp.anedotaspiadas.Anedotas" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fundo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/roxo"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/previousButton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/previous" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/voltarButton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/voltar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/counter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/next" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

Fragment Layout:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.fnsp.anedotaspiadas.Anedotas$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"
            android:textColor="@color/branco"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The buttons are outside the fragment, but I want the buttons be able to switch between fragment, and the textView show the fragment number. I started with the textView, but when i try to print the number, it doesn't print the right number, and when i swipe he sometimes he jumps several numbers.

```
    public class Anedotas extends ActionBarActivity {
        DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);
        static ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        private static TextView counter;
        private ImageButton previous;
        private ImageButton next;
        private ImageButton voltar;



    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anedotas);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
        int aux = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("categoria"));  
        this.setTitle(dbTools.retornaNomeCategoria(aux));


        counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        previous = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previousButton);
        next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        previous = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.voltarButton);


        //buscar as anedotas...
        ar = dbTools.getAnedotasCategoria(aux); 

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        //alteraBarraInferior();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();       
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        //this.finish();
    }

     /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return ar.size();
        }

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private final static String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anedotas, container, false);

            Bundle args = getArguments();
            int i = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            String help = i+"/"+ar.size();
            counter.setText(help);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label)).setText(Html.fromHtml(ar.get(i-1)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? and even now, how can I create a ClickListener to call the previous or the next fragment. 
I thank you for your help and availability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to print current ViewPager position you should use [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) of ViewPager:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        counter.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    }
});
```

To change current position (fragment switching) of ViewPager you should use [ViewPager.setCurrentItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)) method:

```
pager.setCurrentItem(1)
```

1 here is position of your fragment. This should be invoked from onClick listeners of your buttons. Of course, you should change that 1 to correct value.

**Why is it incorrect to print current position from onCreateView?**

ViewPager initialize several fragments at once due to its implementation. For instance, you have 5 fragments in your ViewPager and ViewPager is about to show Fragment #3. It will initialize Fragment #3, Fragment #2 and Fragment #4. So onCreateView of these 3 fragments will be invoked, and that's why you'll get wrong position.